# Is this possible to clear the session whenever browser closed in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my asp.net application, i want to clear the session whenever my browser closed or my tab (if my browser containing multiple tabs)closed.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short version, No.
There's no solid way of a server detecting if the client has closed their browser. It's just the nature of web development's asynchronous pattern.

Long version, if it's really, really important to you;
Put a bit of javascript in the page that sends a regular post to your website in the background and set up a serverside agent or service that disposes of the sessions if it doesnt receive these regular "heartbeat" signals.

You can put a javascript postback onto the page's unload() event but dont rely on it, it doesnt always fire.

Comment: An alternative to setting up a controller action or handler for the heartbeat would be to just set the session timeout to be a minute after your heartbeat interval. Then the browser will automatically dispose it's own session since the cookie would expire.

Comment: Please do not do the javascript approach, as this prevents the timeout feature from doing one of it's key security features - signing the user out if they walk away from their PC. I guarantee if you do this and get a professional security audit on your site, the lack of timeout will be flagged as an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This happens by default whenever you close your browser, and that's not just for ASP.NET. It's for most server-side programming languages that have a session state. Basically, any cookie that is added that doesn't specify an expiration date, will be deleted when the browser is closed.

Where this doesn't apply, is when you close a tab, which is something you will not have any control over because the tab close event will not get sent back to the Web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do that with javascript. Check it at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can check you previous session state on every new browser opening and can Session.clear() or Session.abandon() the previous session.

this will make sure that every time you start application you will get new session.

1. use BasePage in your .net application.
2. Check the session.sessionid on basepage load.
3. More Inforamtion how to detect new session in basepage. [BasePage.Session.Link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45300-base-page-for-detecting-session-timeout-in-aspnetc#/)

Hope this helps
regards
Shaz

```
public class BasePage : Page
{

            protected string mySessionId;   

            private CurrentUser _currentUser;
            public CurrentUser _CurrentUser
            {
                get { return ((CurrentUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["myCurrentUser"]); }
                set { _currentUser = value; }
            }


            protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {

                if (Session["myCurrentUser"] != null)
                {
                    if (_CurrentUser.ProUser)
                    {

                       mySessionId = Session.SessionID; // it means New Session

                    }

                    if (!mySessionId.IsNullOrDefault() && mySessionId != Session.SessionID)
                    {
                        Session.Abandon(); //Abandon current session and start new one                

                    }
                }


            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `cookies` can better meet your requirement here for session management.

> it means that session data should not be stored on the server and
>   should be with your call, so that you don't have to worry about
>   clearing the data on server.

Comment: What do cookies have to do with the browser's close event? If the user closes their browser, nothing gets fired. The cookie will be there, at the client, doing nothing.

Comment: @RenéWolferinkL: it means that session data should not be stored on the server and should be with your call, so that you don't have to worry about clearing the data on server.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.First of all Browser automatically clear session when browser is closed. you can try to capture browser close or tab close event in browser using javascript function like on before unload and on unload. Mostly onbefore unload event captures browser close event in chrome, Firefox, IE 11.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Session_End event of Global.aspx

```
//For Specific Session
Session.Remove("SessionName");

//All the Session
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: that's right - the event will fire if the session timeout period (20 mins for IIS I believe, if not explicitly set) is reached with no further requests from the browser. So it's a guess, and will often occur some time after a user actually stops using your site.

Comment: This is only called when the session times out.